# How to write some non-ascii characters in iso-8859-1 format

Tags: python, file-io, character-encoding, ascii

I have a file, which is not created by me, that contains some non ascii characters. The name of file is `foo.in`. In there there is a turkish word *rahatlattı*. the last character is non-ascii. The file format is `foo.in: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`. When I open the file with less command I see the word is written as `rahatlatt<FD>` Its not a problem for me. But when I try to create a similar file, I couldn't make it in the same way. Up to know, I try the following:

```
import codecs
outputFile = codecs.open("foo2.in","w","ISO-8859-1")
p = unicode('rahatlatt\u0131n')
outputFile.write(p)
outputFile.close()
```

Unfortunatelly, when I checked the content and format of the file I see that format is set as `foo2.in: text/plain; charset=us-ascii` and content is written as `rahatlatt\u0131n`

So, I wonder how can I create a file that is similar to foo.in. The reason behind my request is that, another program takes these files as input and I guess the format of the file is important for it and I cannot run the program with another file format.

Comment: U+0131 can't be encoded in ISO8859-1.

Comment: This is Windows-1254.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams So, what should I do to get the similar output ?

Comment: Figure out what charset encodes U+0131 as 0xfd, and then start with a `unicode` instead of a bytestring.

Comment: Why do you say "file format is foo.in: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"? Did you receive it with an HTTP Content-Type header that says so, or are you using some sort of guessing program?